# How to fill datagridview column with sql scalar function in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, executescalar

hi all i am having a problem with returning a value of a sql server scalar valued function in a specific `datagridview` column, the code is below:-

1- sql function:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ToLocationID](@ID int) 

RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @LocationName varchar(50)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @LocationName=dbo.Location.LocationName FROM Location WHERE LocationID=@ID

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @LocationName

END
```

2-C# Method to execute the function:-

```
public static string MyMethod(int ID) {
            string SqlConnStr = globals.ServerConnStr;
            SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnStr);
            try
            {
                SqlConn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.ToLocationID(@ID)", SqlConn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));
                return  cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

and here is the gridview code:-

```
//GetAllTransfers is a method that executes a stored procedure to return most of the //columns like the column["Date"] below
    dataGridViewList.DataSource = Data.GetAllTransfers();
    dataGridViewList.Columns["Date"].HeaderText = "Date";
    dataGridViewList.Columns.Add("ToLocationID", "To Location");
    dataGridViewList.Columns["ToLocationID"].DisplayIndex = 5;
    dataGridViewList.Columns["ToLocationID"].Tag = Data.MyMethod(1);
```

I just want to fill the column "ToLocationID" with the result of the scalar function from the method "MyMethod", what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously slow. Why not just add this additional piece of data to your GetAllTransfers method? Or change this to an inline table valued function.

Comment: @DatRid I'm not getting any results although the functions works well i am not sure if i am calling it the right way.

Comment: try putting a breakpoint @ return  cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); and see if you are getting data back from the database.

Comment: @SeanLange how can i add it to GetAllTransfers method?

Comment: @CharlesMighty I tried that and the condition is (no condition) and the hit count is (break always currently 0)

Comment: so that means you are not calling the function correctly, I would try putting the function in stored procedure and then call the stored procedure

Comment: Well presumably that method does something to retrieve data from the database? Add another property to your object and add another column to your procedure that populates your Transfer objects.

Comment: I would drop that function like a hot potato. At the very least turn it into an iTVF instead of a scalar.

Comment: please if you can fix the code i will be very thankful cuz i am really new to C#